# Selecting a strictly positive permutation from a stochastic matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, permutations, stochastic-matrices

This question is related to [another one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4346751/finding-a-strictly-positive-good-permutation-in-a-doubly-stochastic-matrix) I recently posed. I am posting this new question because (i) trying to prove that other conjecture seems to have been quite fruitless so far; and (ii) the instant conjecture can be relatively easily verified to hold in low dimensions, since there are only a finite number of possible cases to check. Moreover, a positive answer to the conjecture posed in this question will be sufficient for my purposes.

---

Let $n$ be a positive integer and let $N\equiv\{1,\ldots,n\}$. Consider an $n\times n$ square matrix $\mathbf A\equiv[a_{ij}]_{(i,j)\in N\times N}$ with the following properties:

- each element of the matrix is non-negative;
- the sum of each row is $1$ (that is, $\mathbf A$ is a stochastic matrix);
- the diagonal is strictly positive; and
- each non-zero entry in the matrix is the reciprocal of the number of non-zero entries in that row.

For example:
\begin{align*}
\begin{array}{cccc}
1&0&0&0\\
0&1/2&1/2&0\\
1/3&0&1/3&1/3\\
1/4&1/4&1/4&1/4
\end{array}
\end{align*}

Consider another matrix $\mathbf B\equiv[b_{ij}]_{(i,j)\in N\times N}$ with the following properties:

- each element of $\mathbf B$ is non-negative;
- the sum of each row of $\mathbf B$ is $1$ (that is, $\mathbf B$ is also a stochastic matrix);
- the sum of each column of $\mathbf B$ is the same as the sum of the corresponding column of $\mathbf A$, that is: $$\sum_{i\in N}b_{ij}=\sum_{i\in N}a_{ij}\quad\text{for every $j\in N$; and}$$
- any element of $\mathbf B$ is positive only if the corresponding element in $\mathbf A$ is positive, that is: $$a_{ij}=0\text{ implies }b_{ij}=0\quad\text{for each $(i,j)\in N\times N$.}$$

Note that each specific entry of $\mathbf B$ may take any value otherwise (subject to the above restrictions). It is not constrained to be the reciprocal of the number of non-zero entries in its row, unlike for the entries of $\mathbf A$.

> **Conjecture:** There exists a permutation $\pi:N\to N$ along which the elements of $\mathbf B$ are positive, that is: $$b_{i,\pi(i)}>0\quad\text{for every $i\in N$}.$$

(Note: The assumption that $a_{ii}>0$ for every $i\in N$ ensures the existence of an analogous strictly positive permutation for the matrix $\mathbf A$.)

---

I checked all the possible cases “manually” up to $n\leq3$, and found that the conjecture holds true (unless I made a mistake or omission). I wonder about the general case. Any feedback would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$A=\begin{pmatrix}
1&0&0&0\\1/2&1/2&0&0\\1/3&1/3&1/3&0\\1/4&1/4&1/4&1/4
\end{pmatrix}$
$B=\begin{pmatrix}
1&0&0&0\\1&0&0&0\\1/12&7/12&1/3&0\\0&1/2&1/4&1/4
\end{pmatrix}$
$\pi(1)=1$ , but $\pi(2)$ is undefined.

if this example doesnt work, then i might have misunderstood qn.

Comment: Thank you, it is correct. I was hoping, though, that the apparent truth of the conjecture for $n\in\{1,2,3\}$ indicated it would hold for higher dimensions as well.